# Error when trying to graph an arbitrary 3d function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I'm working on a project for my multivariable calculus class, My objective is to graph an arbitrary function f(x,y), use contour plots to graph the partial derivatives (df/dx, df/dy) and a quiver plot for the gradient of the function, but I have an issue while graphing more complicated functions.

For function inputs like f(x,y) = (x+y)**2 the program works fine an outputs the graph, but when I use an input that requires a more complicated mathematical concept (i.e: f(x,y) = sin(x*y). I get an error:

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

There are a lot of cases of this on stackoverflow, but they all seem to be isolated incidents involving numpy/sympy conflicts. In my program, I am reliant on sympy for creating arbitrary functions, and numpy for array computation, so I'm not sure how to get around this problem.

```
'''
Imports
'''
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')

lims = [-10, 10]
function = sin(x+y)
lam_function = lambdify((x,y),function)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
gX, gY = np.meshgrid(np.arange(lims[0], lims[1], 0.05),
                   np.arange(lims[0], lims[1], 0.05))
z = lam_function(gX, gY)
plot = ax.plot_surface(gX, gY, z, cmap=plt.cm.jet, linewidth=0)
plt.colorbar(plot, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you adjust your example code to not rely upon user input? As it is, I can't try reproducing your error because I don't know what input you're giving the code. You're also importing a lot of stuff that you don't seem to be using, which makes it harder to see what could be going on in your code.

Comment: @Blckknght I've edited the code to show the exact function that raises the error and removed all of the useless imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is easy: You need to specify the which package to use with `lambdify`

```
lam_function = sym.lambdify((x,y), function, "numpy")
```

This will ensure that the resulting functions will be numpy compatible. This works for basic functions like `sin, cos, atan, log` but may fail for more complicated ones such as `sympy.lowergamma`.

Now as to why polinamials work without specifiying `"numpy"` is easy to understand if we have a close look at sympy's [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/1.0/modules/utilities/lambdify.html). If no package is specified sympy will try `python-math`, `numpy` and `mpmath` in exactly this order. Now a python-math `x` is not really different from a numpy `x`, but python-math `sin` is a lot different as it can not handle numpy arrays.

One last thing: Newer versions of sympy (1.1.1+) behave [differently](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html). In these new versions `sympy.lambdify` will try to use `numpy` as default if installed if not resort to `math, mpmath, sympy`.